# The product of two of the four roots of $x^4 -20x^3+ kx^2 + 590x -1992 = 0$ is $24$ the find $k$.

Tags: polynomials

Please help. I tried to solve by taking sum of roots as $20$ and product as $1992$.
No idea how to proceed.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Then the product of two others is $-83$, so $(x^2+ax+24)(x^2+bx-83)=x^4 -20x^3+ kx^2 + 590x -1992$ and undefined coefficients? 3 equations (on $x^3,\, x^2,\, x$), 3 unknowns..

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 3):

As @Alexey Burdin commented, the equation $x^4 -20x^3+ kx^2 + 590x -1992 = 0$ can be rewritten in the form of $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)(x-\theta)=0$, or more specifically, $(x^2+ax+24)(x^2+bx-83)$.

Expanding the product of 2 polynomial and comparing the coefficient, we have

$$a+b=-20$$
$$ab+24-83=k$$
$$24b-83a=590$$

Solving,

$$a=-10, b=-10$$

So

$$k=(-10)(-10)+24-83=41$$

**EDIT:**

Refering back to your situation:

You state that sum of root is 20 and that's correct,as

\begin{align}
0&=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)(x-\theta)\\&=x^4-(\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\theta)x^3+[\alpha\beta+\gamma\theta+(\alpha+\beta)(\gamma+\theta)]x^2-[\alpha\beta(\gamma+\theta)+\gamma\theta(\alpha+\beta)]x+\alpha\beta\gamma\theta
\end{align}

Sub $a=\alpha+\beta$ and $b=\gamma+\theta$ and the product of 2 roots $=24$ and $-83$, it returns to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
x^4 - 20x^3 + kx^2 + 590x - 1992 =&\  (x \pm r_1)(x \pm r_2)(ax^2 + bx + c) \\
=&\ (x^2\pm (r_1 + r_2)x + r_1r_2)(ax^2 + bx + c) \\
=&\ (x^2\pm (r_1 + r_2)x + 24)(ax^2 + bx + c) \\
=&\ ax^4 + bx^3 \pm a(r_1 + r_2)x^3 + cx^2 \pm b(r_1 + r_2)x^2 + 24ax^2 \\
&\ \ \ \pm c(r_1 + r_2)x + 24bx + 24c
\end{align}

Collecting these and setting them equal to the original left and side, x^4 - 20x^3 + kx^2 + 590x - 1992, most things become known:

\begin{align}
&x^4 \text{ and } ax^4 \rightarrow & a = 1 \\
&-20x^3 \text{ and } bx^3 \pm a(r_1 + r_2)x^3 \rightarrow & b \pm (r_1 + r_2) = -20 \\
& kx^2 \text{ and } cx^2 \pm b(r_1 + r_2)x^2 + 24ax^2 \rightarrow & c \pm b(r_1 + r_2) + 24 = k \\
& 590x \text{ and } 24bx \pm c(r_1 + r_2)x \rightarrow & 24b \pm c(r_1 + r_2) = 590 \\
& -1992 \text{ and } 24c \rightarrow & 24c = -1992 \rightarrow c = -83
\end{align}

This gives two equations which may have no solutions (but shouldn't)...I'm going to drop the $\pm$ on $r_1 + r_2$ now:

\begin{align}
b - (r_1 + r_2) = -20 \\
24b + 83(r_1 + r_2) = 590
\end{align}

We can find $b$ by multiplying the first equation by $83$ and adding (to get ride of the $r_1 + r_2$):

$$
83b + 24b - 83(r_1 + r_2) + 83(r_1 + r_2) = -1660 + 590 \\
107b = -1070 \rightarrow b = -10
$$

Which, using the first equation gives that $r_1 + r_2 = b + 20 = -10 + 20 = 10$ (which means the two roots were $6$ and $4$).  Now we find $k$:

$$
k = c - b(r_1 + r_2) + 24 = -83 + 10*10 + 24 = 41
$$